# What is the meaning of an 'event' in the context of painting something with pyside?

Tags: python, pyside

On the tutorial on drawing with pyside [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/drawing/) a `paintEvent` method is overwritten(?) in order to draw something. The actual code is:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)
    self.drawText(event, qp)
    qp.end()
```

What does the object 'event' signifies in this example? Why do I need an 'event'? Why can't I just draw something using something like

```
self.drawText(my_text)
```

with out the 'event' object?

Answer (score 1):

paintEvent is indeed inherited from QWidget. You can see the documentation for it [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent).

The `event` variable is actually a [QPaintEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpaintevent.html), which is explained pretty clearly in the documentation:

> The QPaintEvent class contains event parameters for paint events.
>
> Paint events are sent to widgets that need to update themselves, for
>   instance when part of a widget is exposed because a covering widget
>   was moved.
>
> The event contains a region() that needs to be updated, and a rect()
>   that is the bounding rectangle of that region. Both are provided
>   because many widgets can't make much use of region(), and rect() can
>   be much faster than region().boundingRect().

Basically, it seems that applications can use the information in `event` to only re-paint a part of the QWidget, rather than all of it, for performance reasons. But they can also ignore it and re-paint the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there a way to see that `event` is a `QPaintEvent`? I can imagine there are dozen of 'events'...

Comment: Well, the only event you're going to get in the paintEvent handler is a QPaintEvent. In general your best resource to figure out what event goes with what event handler is to read the documentation. You can see all the event handlers for QWidget in the pyside documentation here: http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#virtual-functions. The documentation for each handler explains what type the event parameter in each is, and what properties it has.